# Is there a way to extract storage summary of Artifactory?

Tags: linux, filesystems, artifactory, jfrog-mission-control

we are currently using Artifactory Version 4.9.0 on O.S: Linux. we know that from Artifactory User Interface, we can see the storage summary of all the repository. 
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Monitoring+Storage

I am looking for a way to write a script (shell) and extract the summary report of Repository Key and Artifacts Size.

We need to know that, where this info is stored. more specifically, in which file we can find this info.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The [Get Storage Summary Info](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-GetStorageSummaryInfo) REST resource is one you are looking for.